# Ajax trying to execute PHP page brings me to a new page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, input, onkeypress

I am trying to get a live chat working using PHP and mysql and AJAX. It is almost completely functioning, except I cant seem to figure out how to submit the chat message without reloading a page. I have a page, sendchat.php, that takes input from the previous page and enters the data into a database. I am trying to use a text input field and when the user clicks the enter key, it would execute the PHP page with the details needed to send to sendchat.php without actually loading or refreshing the page. This is what I have so far:

```
 <form id="send-message-area">
            <p>Your message: </p>
            <input type="text" id="sendie" maxlength = '100' onkeydown="onChatEnter(this);"></textarea>
        </form>

    </div>
    </td></tr></table>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">



 function onChatEnter(str) {
      if(event.key === 'Enter') {

   $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sendchat.php?msg=" + str ,
                                success : function() { 

                    // here is the code that will run on client side after running clear.php on server



                }
            });

}

 </script>
```

All it does is try to load the url, but its not trying to find sendchat.php or send the data. Instead it just tries to load a blank page. Where am I going wrong here? Everything seems spelled correctly and case sensitive. I check if the user pressed enter when they press a key. If they did, I am loading an AJAX function to execute a PHP page. Yet, it is not doing that. Just for FYI, I do not want a button there to be clicked.

EDIT:

I tried the suggestions below and still nothing. I decided to try a different approach now. Still doesn't work.

```
<script>
function updatechat(str) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {

    if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("sendie").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("sendie").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","sendchat.php?msg="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
</script>

 <p>Your message: </p>
            <input type="text" id="sendie" maxlength = '100' onkeypress="updatechat(this.value);"></input>
```

Comment: You need to prevent the `<form>` from submitting which the default behaviour is to submit. You can use the `onsubmit` attribute on the form and return false or `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: return false or using preventdefault is not working. And for some reason it doesn't seem to be even running sendchat.php. It's just loading a blank document.

Comment: A few questions for you: “All it does is try to load the url” - how do you know that?  “not trying to find sendchat.php” - how do you know that?  (These things aren’t in the post). Use the network tab in browser console to see what is being sent and received. Post that, and I’ll try to help. I suspect the problem is in your php script.

Comment: @user1924218 instead of `innerHTML` use `value` i.e :`document.getElementById("sendie").value=this.responseText;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#send-message-area").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Still nothing. I did an edit for a different approach. Still nothing.

Comment: It must be something with your DOM structure. Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how.. But I fixed it.. I think it had to do with giving the input a name along with the ID. See below:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function updatechat(str) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {


    if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("sendie").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("sendie").innerHTML=this.responseText;

    }
  }
  var planetloc = document.getElementById("loc").value;
chaturl = "sendchat.php?msg="+str+"&loc="+planetloc;
sendie.value="";

  xmlhttp.open("GET",chaturl,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

This was the code I used for the html:

```
<p>Your message: </p>
            <input type='text' id='sendie' name='sendie' maxlength = '100' onkeypress='updatechat(this.value);'></input>
            <input type='hidden' id='loc' name='loc' value='$chatroom'></input>";
```

I also added `chaturl` to combine the ajax page I needed along with the parameters passed to it. It seemed by creating a variable for that it solved other issues too.